# Sed command for deleting 1 line after pattern matching (showing error : bad flag in substitute command: ',')

Tags: bash, sed

I have been trying the following command on my Mac computer,for deleting 2 lines(including the line containing pattern and the consecutive line)

```
   sed -i '' -e "s/.*GAII02_0001:1:15:14342:18862#0/1.*/ , +1d"  output.fa new.fa
```

But I am getting following error :

```
`sed: 1: "s/.*GAII02_0001:1:15:14 ...": bad flag in substitute command: ','`
```

Sample input :

> GAII02_0001:1:94:1703:4111#0/1
>   ATTTAGGGATTTAAGGATTAAGGATTAAGGATCCAGAGATTTAGGGATTTA
>   GAII02_0001:1:15:14342:18862#0/1
>   TTAGAGATTTAGGGATTTAGGGATATAGGGATTTAGTGATTTAGGGATTTA
>   GAII02_0001:1:7:12506:5001#0/1
>   AATCCCTAAATCTCTGGATCCTTAATCCTTAATCCTTAAATCCCTAAATCC

Sample output:

> GAII02_0001:1:94:1703:4111#0/1
>   ATTTAGGGATTTAAGGATTAAGGATTAAGGATCCAGAGATTTAGGGATTTA
>   GAII02_0001:1:7:12506:5001#0/1
>   AATCCCTAAATCTCTGGATCCTTAATCCTTAATCCTTAAATCCCTAAATCC

Comment: Could you post sample input and desired output?

Comment: I have added to the query.

Comment: The error message as such is unsurprising; `,` is not a valid flag.  What do you expect it to do?  It looks roughly like you are mixing up the `s/regex/replacement/` command with the `/regex/,+1` addressing syntax (where the +1 extension is not supported in OSX `sed` anyway, I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 sed '/GAII02_0001:1:15:14342:18862#0\/1/{N;d;}' foo.txt
```

This will give you the desired output

```
GAII02_0001:1:94:1703:4111#0/1
ATTTAGGGATTTAAGGATTAAGGATTAAGGATCCAGAGATTTAGGGATTTA
GAII02_0001:1:7:12506:5001#0/1
AATCCCTAAATCTCTGGATCCTTAATCCTTAATCCTTAAATCCCTAAATCC
```

What this does is it appends the next line to the pattern space with `N`, and then deletes both lines using `d`.

Comment: That's weird, maybe it's just a version thing, but I have edited the command see if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete two lines if you read the next one after a match

Also note that I've escaped the `/` in the search string as otherwise it would have terminated the expression.

And that you had typed it as a substitution, and it's just a matcher

```
$ sed -e "/.*GAII02_0001:1:15:14342:18862#0\/1.*/{N;d;}" testfile
GAII02_0001:1:94:1703:4111#0/1
ATTTAGGGATTTAAGGATTAAGGATTAAGGATCCAGAGATTTAGGGATTTA
GAII02_0001:1:7:12506:5001#0/1
AATCCCTAAATCTCTGGATCCTTAATCCTTAATCCTTAAATCCCTAAATCC
```

Comment: Same answer as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak '/GAII02_0001:1:15:14342:18862#0\/1./,+1d' file
```

the error caused by the '/' in the pattern. escape it will be work..

`-i.bak` will backup you file with a new file file.bak. care you metadata~~

don't mind my english. (:

Comment: HI..Thank you for reply.It is showing me this : sed: 1: "/GAII02_0001:1:15:14342 ...": expected context address

Comment: The `.` at the end of the regex address must not be there or it won't match.